# NServiceBus: System.Transactions.TransactionException: The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions

Tags: nservicebus, msdtc

I am getting this exception on my *subscriber* when I try to save a record to a database from within my Handle(T value) method in my IHandleMessages implementation.  Does anyone know why that would happen?  I think I remember that NServiceBus uses distributed transactions to make the handling of messages transactional, but I have no idea why it doesn't just "work" after running the "RunMeFirst.bat" file on both machines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.  It looks like I needed to enable the "Allow Inbound" option under MSDTC Security settings.  Does anyone know why the RunMeFirst.bat doesn't set this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem are (as @skb said) the MSDTC Security settings, and you can find a detailed explanation on how to set this permissions on this MSDN forum response: [The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/7172223f-acbe-4472-8cdf-feec80fd2e64/).