# Calling Entity Framework from a NServiceBus method causes an error

Tags: entity-framework, nservicebus, msdtc

I have a solution that has a self hosted WCF Service.  That service connects to EF and can read and write just fine.

In the same solution I also host an NServiceBus endpoint.  It gets event from a separate running solution.

When I run the NServiceBus project (by itself) it seems to be working fine, until I try to query my database.  When I do that I get this EntityException:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

The inner exception is a TransactionException with a message of:

> The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions

Both my NServiceBus and WCF Service projects are using the exact same configurations and EF Projects.  I don't get why one is failing and the other is not.

I did some Googling and came across this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924%28BTS.20%29.aspx that showed me how to setup MSDTC, and I did it on my client machine.  But it had no effect.

I also found this question that says it needs to be set: [NServiceBus: System.Transactions.TransactionException: The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442227/nservicebus-system-transactions-transactionexception-the-partner-transaction-m).  But it does not say why or where.

Do I need to setup MSDTC on my db server?  If so, why?  What is MSDTC?

**Why does running from an NServiceBus hosted process cause this error?**

**UPDATE**: I found this [link](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/6493) that helped me understand what DTC does.  It also showed me how to turn it off if needed:

```
using (TransactionScope sc=new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
     YourDatabaseHandler.SaveMyStuff(whatever);
```

Though it sounds like it is a good thing in many situations.

Comment: Are you using TransactionScope? What transport is NServiceBus using? Is it MSMQ with transactional queues?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - I am not intentionally using TransactionScope.  If it is used by EF under the hood I don't know about it.  NServiceBus is using MSMQ with transactional queues.

Comment: @Vaccano - suppressing the transaction is a bad idea.  doing this means that you are not operating against your database and the message queue in the same transaction.  you could commit your database transaction and abort the message queue transaction, meaning you'll execute the same dataase transaction twice.  there should be very few exceptions where you wouldn't want this atomicity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since NSB is using a transactional queue, your going to be participating in a distributed transaction.  This means that each machine participating will have to vote on whether or not to complete a transaction.  This is done via the Distributed Transaction Coordinator(MSDTC).  This will have to be running on both machines(and if you are using other DBs like Oracle there is an additional service).  To manage MSDTC, go to Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> Distributed Transaction Coordinator -> Local DTC.  Right clicking on that node you will find all the configuration including security.

Comment: "This will have to be running on both machines" - Do you mean my DB Server?  I would really like to know why.  My NServiceBus process is just calling EF to save to the db.  How could EF know that I am getting my data from NServiceBus?  I could just as easily save it to a file and load it in in another process and then save it.  How does the the process know that the data I am saving is part of a "Distributed Transaction"?

Comment: @Vaccano - ef doesn't know about nservicebus being involved.  The transactionscope used by nservicebus, though, is in scope during the execution of the handler.  ef will try to enlist in the transaction that is already active.  if dtc is not running on both machines (yes, the machine executing the handler and the database server) with network access enabled, this will fail.  this is what you want in almost every case because you want atomicity between the message queue transaction and the database transaction.